# how to change browser URL without page referesh in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the code below but the page still refreshes.
I'm trying to change the url or the page without refreshing it.

```
//getting the url from browser
var uri = window.location.toString();
//checking whether the url has anything after '?'
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) 
//then take the url before '?'
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));

//And push this to browser
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
```

Comment: Please improve question formatting... Also, recommended reading to start: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

history.replaceState should not refresh the page. If page is reloading then you have something else in the code, like, for example, form submission. `preventDefault()` method can help you cancel the event.

```
<form>
    <button id="bt" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


//getting the url from browser
var uri = window.location.toString();
var bt = document.getElementById("bt");

//checking whether the url has anything after "?"
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    //then take the url before "?"
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    bt.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // If you remove this line, the page will refresh and the form will be submitted.
        history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri); 
    });
}
```